# Multiple 802.11 associations with single physical antenna?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, 802.11

My Question is as an access point with a single PHY# hardware antenna is able to create multiple virtual interfaces and and announce multiple SSID

Now, as we can create multiple virtual interfaces in STA side too, so can we anyhow simply or tweaking cfg80211 code associate with multiple SSIDs from single STA.

Both SSIDs are on same frequency for now.

Steps that i followed

created Vifs :-

```
iw dev wlan0 interface add vlan0 type station
iw dev wlan0 interface add vlan1 type station
```

I have two separate wpa_supplicant configuration files, which i usually use one at a time, now using both at once

```
wpa_suppicant -ivlan0 -Dnl80211 -cNEXTRA4419.conf

wpa_suppicant -ivlan1 -Dnl80211 -cNEIGHBOUR.conf
```

But something i don't know what i am missing, and unable to link up which is not allowing this setup to work.

Comment: Think about SSIDs like VLANs. Most end-devices don't understand VLAN tags, so they are limited to using a single VLAN per interface.

Comment: then how its possible to host multiple ssid on same hardware using hostapd ?

Comment: You may as well ask how do bridges (switches and WAPs are bridges) understand VLANs? The hardware is basically the same as what is in an end-device. There is nothing to keep a PC from understanding VLANs because some server software can, and it can run on the same PC as a desktop OS which does not.

Comment: more over i am unable to understand and correlate it with vlans as dot1q tagging is quite possible in linux machines

Comment: There are end-devices based on versions of Linux that do not understand VLAN tags.

Comment: its not problem almost  all hardware support . you need to update kernal or load 8021q module .. lets dont go there , lets discuss above mentioned possiblity

Comment: You made my point, which is that you need the proper software to do what you want to do. I don't know of any off the top of my head.

Comment: ok lets wait if someone can answer else i ll attach bounty

Comment: well @RonMaupin thanks i understand what u r tring to say.. but i am looking for that missing part only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to multiple WiFi networks via multiple virtual interfaces](http://superuser.com/questions/977618/unable-to-connect-to-multiple-wifi-networks-via-multiple-virtual-interfaces)

Comment: @RonMaupin 802.1q is not involved here at all. This is 802.11, not 802.3. The wireless medium offers possibilities like this that are not possible with a physical point-to-point connection.

Comment: @DanielB, I understand that. I was drawing a parallel.

Comment: @RonMaupin It's just that you can't. Ethernet and Wireless LAN are nothing alike.

Comment: @DanielB, I absolutely know that. You just don't seem to get what I was after.

Comment: No, because there is nothing to get. *Every* WiFi device understands SSIDs. And, within the driver limits (as indicated in my answer), WiFi devices can serve or connect to multiple SSIDs. It is *nothing* like VLANs. There is also no need for some wild speculation, because he wouldn't have been able to create the virtual interface in the first place if the driver didn't support it. So the driver *does* support it and this entire discussion and attempt to draw (inappropriate) parallels was completely pointless.

Answer (score 3):

This is of course possible. Your configuration seems correct. You can connect to as many networks as the driver allows. For example, my router reports (`iw list`):

```
valid interface combinations:
     * #{ managed } <= 2048, #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ IBSS } <= 1,
       total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
[...]
```

But there's also the catch: `#channels <= 1` - a single radio can also support one channel at a time. That means all 2048 networks would have to reside on a single channel. While the radio could jump between channels, I haven't seen any driver that implements this.

---

So, I tried with my trusty Thinkpad. It has an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 card, yielding the following specs:

```
valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1,
           total <= 2, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
         * #{ managed } <= 2,
           total <= 2, #channels <= 1
```

Barely good enough for a test! I used the Arch Linux live CD 2016.10.01. I created only one additional interface and used the main interface too:

```
iw dev wlp3s0 interface add vlan0 type managed
```

While I can *create* more interfaces, only two can be brought up at the same time.

I then connected to my real network (using the `wifi-menu` command, because I’m lazy), so I can SSH in:

```
root@archiso ~ # iw dev
phy#0
        Interface vlan0
                ifindex 5
                wdev 0x2
                addr 08:11:96:01:82:49
                type managed
                channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
                txpower 15.00 dBm
        Interface wlp3s0
                ifindex 4
                wdev 0x1
                addr 08:11:96:01:82:48
                type managed
                txpower 15.00 dBm
```

Using a *different router* I then created another network on channel 6 (no encryption) and connected to it:

```
root@archiso ~ # ip link set wlp3s0 up
root@archiso ~ # iw dev wlp3s0 connect -w OpenWrt-1
wlp3s0 (phy #0): connected to e0:91:f5:08:12:9d
root@archiso ~ # ping -I wlp3s0 -c 3 fe80::e291:f5ff:fe08:129d
PING fe80::e291:f5ff:fe08:129d(fe80::e291:f5ff:fe08:129d) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::e291:f5ff:fe08:129d%wlp3s0: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.33 ms
64 bytes from fe80::e291:f5ff:fe08:129d%wlp3s0: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.53 ms
64 bytes from fe80::e291:f5ff:fe08:129d%wlp3s0: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.38 ms

--- fe80::e291:f5ff:fe08:129d ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.382/2.084/2.537/0.504 ms
```

I was able to replicate this while both connections were encrypted, too.

Here’s how `wifi-menu` starts `wpa_supplicant`:

```
wpa_supplicant -q -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant_wlp3s0.pid -i wlp3s0 -D nl80211,wext -c/run/network/wpa_supplicant_wlp3s0.conf
```

And this is the config file it generated:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
network={
proto=RSN WPA
psk="123456789"
ssid="OpenWrt-1"
}
```

Comment: but i am taking about the case in which both access pints are broadcsting SSIDs with same freq and \on same channel

Comment: But are they? Please provide the “valid interface combinations” part of `iw list` output. Also, the (relevant) output of `iw dev wlan0 scan`. I’ll also try to replicate this whole endeavor later.

Comment: alright @Daniel

Comment: @8zero2.ops I tried it, it works as expected. Please update your question with the “valid interface combinations” part of iw list output and the relevant output of `iw dev wlan0 scan`.